# Is there a way to insert HTML code into a document that is comparable to the simplicity of inserting css/js code?

Tags: html

I know that it is best practice to have separate files for CSS and JS so that this:

```
<head>
  <style>
    <!--CSS code -->
    <!--CSS code -->
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML code -->
    <!--HTML code --> 
  <script>
    <!--JS code -->
    <!--JS code -->
  </script>
</body>
```

becomes this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-blackjack-file.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML code -->
    <!--HTML code -->
  <script src="my-javascript-file.js"></script>
</body>
```

But is there an equally simple way to do this for the html portion of the code for the sake of better organization? I have seen some suggestions online for including html pages, but they seem to be talking about iframes and use some fairly complex (for me) javascript. Is there something more akin to

```
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="html" href="my-html-file.html">
</body>
```

in order to separate a long document into several files that run as if they were on the same page?

Comment: Just a tip, set this files inside a folder called assets or sources and then create folder to js, css and img

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño do you mean that I should have one folder called "assets" that contains 3 folders (one for js files, one for css files, and one for images)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [work in progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) and may (or may not) be supported in the next version.

Until then, unless you output the HTML through some server-side technology such as JSPs or Velocity, which support templating, you can only use iframes or AJAX as a workaround for including HTML.

Comment: I did not downvote. How did you come to that conclusion? Also, my answer was posted around the same time as yours (seconds apart).

Comment: No worries, there is no way to identify.  There was a low volume of activity and I assumed.  I shouldn't have done that

Comment: Fair enough. I'm aware of the whole "conflict of interest" policy when it comes to SO answers. I never downvote any answers (no matter how I feel about them), if I add one in a question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the development environment you can use partial views.

```
<body>
@Html.RenderPartial("descriptiveNameHere.html");
<script src="my-javascript-file.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or something to that effect.  There is additional syntax of course, but maybe this will put you on the track you're looking for.

Ultimately you will still have an html file with your "HTML Code".  But if you're looking to reduce the complexity of a large file by moving chunks into external files, partial views are a way to do so.

Comment: You might want to add that this is only applicable to asp.net.

Comment: There is a note right at the top that says depending on his environment....He did not include what that was in the question.  So why the down vote?

Comment: @Vasan I think this answer is helpful. I'm going to look into it a bit further before accepting it, though, since I am not at all familiar with the various development environments available.